# Python Library Function Issue

Tags: python

I have a text file named "movies.txt" that inside are those lines:

```
 The_Godfather Francis_Ford_Coppola Crime 1972
 The_Dark_Knight Christofer_Nolan Action 2008
 Pulp_Fiction Quentin_Tarantino Drama 1994
```

From the file I want to extract those lines and use them with other functions (search by year / genere ect).
To open the file i use:

```
f=open("movies.txt","r")
s=f.read()
print(s)
f.close()
```

But it seems that i am missing something, here is the sample of the code:

```
f=open("movies.txt","r")
s=f.read()
print(s)
f.close()

def search_movie_by_name(name,path):
    mystring = path
    for i in path:
        if word in mystring:
            print("Found")
```

Is it something to do with the code? or with how i open it?

Comment: Can you give us a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you're running/calling this?

Comment: So what is the output or error you get?

Comment: def search_movie_by_name(Baywatch,path):
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hey adonis, i do not get any output

Comment: I assume you don't get the "Found" printed out. Your code does not make any sense to me. You have to provide more information. You are iterating through "path" - so what is this variable? A file? Then you have to open() it. Why do you create a variable "mystring" which is the same as path? You could use "path" . What is "word" ? Is it the "name" variable? Where do you call search_movie_by_name and with which parameters? Please give a lot more information.

Comment: Also, why do you iterate through path with i, if you never use it?

Comment: First, thanks for all the responses, my question is simple (lets put aside the code i wrote i know it has its problems).
Does the code needs to begin with reading the file, closing it, and the functions below it?
Or does the code begins with reading the file, function, and then closing it?

Comment: You are supposed to open the file, read it and then close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code doesn't make much sense. Undeclared variables, unused file contents, etc. I believe what you want to do is open the file and iterate through the lines like this:

```
def search_movie_by_name(name, path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if name in line:
                print("Found")
                return line
```

Example:

```
In [10]: def search_movie_by_name(name, path):
    ...:     with open(path, 'r') as f:
    ...:         for line in f.readlines():
    ...:             if name in line:
    ...:                 print("Found")
    ...:                 return
    ...: 

In [11]: search_movie_by_name("Godfather", "movies.txt")
Found
```

It opens the file at the given `path` and iterates through the lines until it finds the line with the `name` given and prints "Found."

With limited modification to your code:

```
f=open("movies.txt","r")
s=f.read()
print(s)
f.close()

def search_movie_by_name(name, file_content):
    for line in file_content.splitlines():
        if name in line:
            print("Found")
```

Example:

```
In [18]: f=open("movies.txt","r")
    ...: s=f.read()
    ...: print(s)
    ...: f.close()
    ...: 
    ...: def search_movie_by_name(name,file_content):
    ...:     for line in file_content.splitlines():
    ...:         if name in line:
    ...:             print("Found")
    ...:             

The_Godfather Francis_Ford_Coppola Crime 1972
The_Dark_Knight Christofer_Nolan Action 2008
Pulp_Fiction Quentin_Tarantino Drama 1994


In [19]: search_movie_by_name("Godfather", s)
Found
```

Comment: I do not understand the file_content, name is for the movie name, file contect is the location of the row?

Comment: @Tom I've added examples of both methods being used.

Comment: thanks, so eventuly if i understand right, the file contect is from s instead of the file text itself, that's why i didnt had any clue how to advance.